# Missing Leading Zeros in SQL Export to Excel Loop

Tags: sql, vb.net, excel, loops, export

New VB programmer here. I am exporting a SQL table to an Excel file using the following method below. However, when I create the file in excel, my leading zeros for my primary key are missing due to being converted to numbers instead of text. This is due to the information coming from the datatable to excel. I am wondering what I can do to keep my leading zeros.

FYI - my primary key is 6 digits with only a few that are missing a single 0 in the beginning of them. There are many other columns and rows that get put into the excel file after the first column which all work perfectly. It is only the first column primary keys which i need to change the format somehow.

Also, I am using this excel file to then upload into SQL and the missing 0 on some of the primary keys maks my program create a new record.

I was thinking the main change could take place here but I cannot figure out how to do so:

```
                'Export the Columns to excel file
                For Each dc In datatableMain.Columns
                    colIndex = colIndex + 1
                    oSheet.Cells(1, colIndex) = dc.ColumnName
                Next

                For Each dr In datatableMain.Rows
                    rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
                    colIndex = 1

                    For Each dc In datatableMain.Columns
                        colIndex = colIndex + 1
                        oSheet.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = dr(dc.ColumnName)
                    Next
                Next
```

Full Code Below:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim dataAdapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()
        Dim dataSet As New DataSet
        Dim command As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
        Dim datatableMain As New System.Data.DataTable()
        Dim connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection


        connection.ConnectionString = "Server=myserver;Database=mydatabase;User Id=xxxx;Password=xxxxx"
        command.Connection = connection
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        'You can use any command select
        command.CommandText = "Select * from MYTABLE"
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command


        Dim f As FolderBrowserDialog = New FolderBrowserDialog
        Try
            If f.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                'This section help you if your language is not English.
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = _
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")
                Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
                Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
                Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
                oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
                oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)
                oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)

                Dim dc As System.Data.DataColumn
                Dim dr As System.Data.DataRow
                Dim colIndex As Integer = 0
                Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0

                'Fill data to datatable
                connection.Open()

                dataAdapter.Fill(datatableMain)
                connection.Close()

                'Export the Columns to excel file
                For Each dc In datatableMain.Columns
                    colIndex = colIndex + 1
                    oSheet.Cells(1, colIndex) = dc.ColumnName
                Next

                For Each dr In datatableMain.Rows
                    rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
                    colIndex = 1

                    For Each dc In datatableMain.Columns
                        colIndex = colIndex + 1
                        oSheet.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = dr(dc.ColumnName)
                    Next
                Next

                'Set final path
                Dim fileName As String = "\" + fname.Text + ".xlsx"
                Dim finalPath = f.SelectedPath + fileName
                txtPath.Text = finalPath
                oSheet.Columns.AutoFit()
                'Save file in final path
                oBook.SaveAs(finalPath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Type.Missing, _
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, _
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)

                'Release the objects
                ReleaseObject(oSheet)
                oBook.Close(False, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
                ReleaseObject(oBook)
                oExcel.Quit()
                ReleaseObject(oExcel)
                'Some time Office application does not quit after automation: 
                'so i am calling GC.Collect method.
                GC.Collect()

                MessageBox.Show("Exported!")

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub ReleaseObject(ByVal o As Object)
    Try
        While (System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o) > 0)
        End While
    Catch
    Finally
        o = Nothing
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Try setting the Cells NumberFormat property to "000000".

Comment: How would I do that for only the first column which contains the primary keys? All my other columns otherwise format perfectly.

Comment: The way Telestia suggested would be best.  You are setting the format of the excel Column.  Setting to "@" is for text formatting,  setting it to "000000" will give you a number with leading 0's, padded to 6 places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually just had a similar problem about 10 minutes ago! I needed to get a 30-something digit from one book to another and it was overflowing everything. Try setting the formatting of the column *before* writing to the cells. My code was             `Worksheets(i).Range("D:D").NumberFormat = "@"` This will tell Excel to interperate the data "as is" instead of trying to guess what you want.

Comment: Worked like a charm Telestia. Thank you for this friend!

Comment: I'm glad! That means it *actually* worked instead of me just conveniently breaking things in direction of working!

Answer (score 0):

I found this question looking to fix this same issue in a generic function I have, that's used by a couple programs I've created. Due to that variety of data sources I couldn't hard code which columns to set the `NumberFormat` on. In order to get around it I leveraged the loop I have to output column headers. My code is below for those needing a little more of a dynamic solution. Note, there are a couple references to 'EL' that's an instance of a custom error logging object in the same solution, that can just be ignored/modified:

```
''' <summary>
''' Function to take a data table and output its contents to an Excel spreadsheet. Returns a string with any errors (Nothing if successful)
''' </summary>
''' <param name="D">The datatable to be output</param>
''' <param name="epath">The full file path to log errors to</param>
''' <param name="SAName">The full file path to save the created Excel workbook to</param>
''' <param name="Parent">The function calling for data to be output</param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Function ResOut(ByVal D As DataTable, ByVal epath As String, ByVal SAName As String, ByVal Parent As String) As String
    '
    Dim res As String = ""
    Dim E As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook = Nothing
    Dim ws As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet = Nothing
    Dim x As Long = 0
    Dim f As Long = 1
    Dim Rng As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range = Nothing
    Dim q As String
    Dim Str_Columns As New List(Of String) 'Holds the list of column letters that need forced to Text format in order to retain leading zeroes in the data 
    'that will be placed there
    'Check that the passed in table has data
    If D.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        res = "No data was returned by " & Parent
    End If

    If res = "" Then
        'Create a workbook for the data and capture the workbook and sheet for ease of reference
        Try
            wb = E.Workbooks.Add
            ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

            'Define the range
            q = ColNumToStr(D.Columns.Count, epath)
            Rng = ws.Range("A2:" & q & D.Rows.Count + 1)
        Catch ex As Exception
            res = "Encountered an error while creating the new workbook to export the results to. No data can be returned."
            EL.AddErr(res & " ResOut was called by " & Parent & ". Error Details: " & ex.Message, epath)
        End Try

        'Fill in headers
        If res = "" Then
            Try
                For Each c As DataColumn In D.Columns
                    ws.Range("A1").Offset(0, x).Value = c.ColumnName
                    x = x + 1
                Next
            Catch ex As Exception
                res = "Encountered an error while filling in the column headers. This will prevent any data from being returned."
                EL.AddErr(res & " ResOut was called by " & Parent & ". Error Details: " & ex.Message, epath)
            End Try
        End If

        'Setup the step & frequency for the Step Progress bar
        'Dim t() As Long = s.StatSetup(QR.Rows.Count, 58, "Query Runner\ResOut\" & QName, Replace(My.Settings.EPath, "<user>", Environment.UserName) & DStamp() & " Query Scheduler Log.txt")
        'f = t(0)
        'SProg.Step = t(1)

        'Create the array
        Dim OArr(D.Rows.Count, x) As Object

        'Convert the datatable to a 2D array
        If res = "" Then
            Try
                'Fill it
                x = 0
                For r As Long = 0 To D.Rows.Count - 1 Step 1
                    Dim dr As DataRow = D.Rows(r)

                    For c As Integer = 0 To D.Columns.Count - 1 Step 1
                        OArr(r, c) = dr.Item(c).ToString

                        'Check if this item is a # with leading zeroes (making sure we haven't already added the column to the list of such columns)
                        If Not (Str_Columns.Contains(ColNumToStr(c + 1, epath))) And Strings.Left(dr.Item(c), 1) = "0" Then
                            Str_Columns.Add(ColNumToStr(c + 1, epath))
                        End If 'else the column is in the list already or the item does not dictate it's inclusion
                    Next
                    x = x + 1
                Next
            Catch ex As Exception
                res = "Encountered an error while outputing the " & x + 1 & "-th record of " & D.Rows.Count & ". No data will be output."
                EL.AddErr(res & " ResOut was called by " & Parent & ". Error Details: " & ex.Message, epath)
            End Try
        End If

        'output the array to the target range
        If res = "" Then
            'First force Text format where needed to retain leading zeroes
            Try
                For Each c As String In Str_Columns
                    q = c
                    ws.Range(c & ":" & c).NumberFormat = "@"
                Next
            Catch ex As Exception
                res = "Encountered an error while changing column " & q & " to TEXT in order to retain leading zeroes in the " & ws.Range(q & 1).Value & "data."
                E.Visible = True
                wb.Activate()
                EL.AddErr(res & " ResOut was called by " & Parent & ". Error Details: " & ex.Message & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Inner Exception: " & ex.InnerException.Message _
                          , epath)
            End Try

            Try
                Rng.Value = OArr

                'Save the workbook
                wb.SaveAs(SAName)
                wb.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
            Catch ex As Exception
                res = "Encountered an error during the export of the results. Some data may have been exported. Review the contents of the Excel workbook that will " _
                    & "be visible following this message for more details."
                E.Visible = True
                wb.Activate()
                EL.AddErr(res & " ResOut was called by " & Parent & ". Error Details: " & ex.Message, epath)
            End Try
        Else
            'Close the workbook without saving
            wb.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
        End If

        'Cleanup the application
        Try
            E.Quit()
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(E)
            E = Nothing
            wb = Nothing
            ws = Nothing
            Rng = Nothing
            OArr = Nothing
            f = Nothing
            x = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            EL.AddErr("Encountered an error while cleaning up the resources used in JMLib\ResOut. ResOut was called by " & Parent & ". Error Details: " & ex.Message, epath)
        End Try
    End If

    Return res
End Function
```